# Changing the Primitive-String a String-Object References

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Ignoring all best practices, I have a rather academic question that I'll ask for curiosity's sake.

As you know, you can add custom properties to a string Object:

```
var s = new String("initial string");
var s.customProperty = "Please Don't Forget about me";
```

Is it possible (without creating a new string object), to change the string-primitive that **"s"** references?

Specifically, I want to change **"s"** (above), so that **s == "new string"**, yet after making this change, I want **s.customProperty** to still point to the string-primitive: **"Please Don't Forget about me"**. Again, I want to achieve this without having to create any new string objects.

```
var s = new String("initial string");
var s.customProperty = "Please Don't Forget about me";

// What code must preceed the following "if statement" in order
// for it to return "true" (giving the restrictions I described
// in the paragraphs of this post)?

if(s == "new string" && s.customProperty == "Please Don't Forget about me")
{
    console.log("true");
}
else
{
    console.log("false");
}
```

In other words, is possible to change a string object's reference-pointer without losing or cloning all custom properties that have been added to that string object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the string-primitive that a "s" references?

No. The [*[[StringData]]*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string-constructor-string-value) (ES6) / [*[[PrimitiveValue]]*](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.5) (ES5) it contains is an [internal slot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) and cannot be mutated.

> … without having to create any new string objects.

There's no way around that.

What you possibly can do is to subclass `String` and overwrite all methods to refer to a mutable property, but that advice is as good as "don't use `String` objects". See also the answers to the inverse problem [Is there a way to Object.freeze() a JavaScript Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34907311/1048572).

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. Fleeting thoughts . . . : String objects would be interestingly more flexible if they referenced something similar to an object-property instead of an internal slot.

Comment: @LonnieBest: Immutability rules it all :-) If you want stateful instances, just use standard objects with a `toString` method.

Answer (score -1):

[String prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) to the rescue!

So basically something like this:

```
String.prototype.customProperty = "Please Don't Forget about me";
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
"Your string".customProperty
```

Comment: Now _all_ your `String` objects have that property, I don't think that's what the OP is after.