# Passing Proxy object as thisArgument to apply throws TypeError: Illegal Invocation

Tags: javascript, javascript-proxy

I'm trying to trap calls to `Storage`. As far as I can tell there are two ways to call either `setItem` or `getItem`:

```js
    sessionStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");
    let item = sessionStorage.getItem("foo");

    Storage.prototype.setItem.call(sessionStorage, "foo", "bar");
    let item2 = Storage.prototype.getItem.call(sessionStorage, "foo");
```

Using `sessionStorage` in Code Snippet throws a security error, so [here's the code in JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8ckytuz/)

**TLDR**: I can handle all cases if I do this, but it seems hacky. Is there a better/cleaner way to accomplish my goal? (NOTE: I don't have control over caller, this is why I'm covering both cases):

```
try {
    console.log("\n\n");
    let ss = new Proxy(sessionStorage, {
        get: function (getTarget, p) {
            if (p === "__this") {
                // kinda hacky, but allows us to unwrap Proxy for binding
                return getTarget;
            }
            console.log("sessionStorage.get proxy called")
            return new Proxy(Reflect.get(getTarget, p), {
                apply(applyTarget, thisArg, argArray) {
                    console.log("sessionStorage.get.apply called");
                    Reflect.apply(applyTarget, getTarget, argArray);
                }
            })
        },
    });

    SP = new Proxy(Object.create(Storage.prototype), {
        get: function (getTarget, p) {
            console.log("Storage.get proxy called")
            return new Proxy(Reflect.get(getTarget, p), {
                apply(applyTarget, thisArg, argArray) {
                    console.log("Storage.get.apply called");
                    try {
                        return Reflect.apply(applyTarget, thisArg, argArray);
                    } catch (e) {
                        // unpack proxy if we're double-wrapped (both target and thisArg are Proxy)
                        return Reflect.apply(applyTarget, thisArg.__this, argArray);
                    }
                }
            })
        },
    });
    SPW = {};
    Object.defineProperty(SPW, 'prototype', {
        value: SP,
        configurable: false,
    });
    si = SPW.prototype.setItem;
    gi = SPW.prototype.getItem;
    si.call(ss, "foo", "3");
    console.log(`Storage.prototype.getItem: ${gi.call(ss, "foo")}`);
    console.log(`Storage.prototype Worked`)
} catch (e) {
    console.log(`Storage.prototype Caught ${e.stack}`);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mvh82tu/).

Result:

```
Storage.get proxy called
Storage.get proxy called
Storage.get.apply called
Storage.get.apply called
Storage.prototype.getItem: 3
Storage.prototype Worked
```

I don't see any other way than including a "hidden" `__this` property so that the caller can "unwrap" the `Proxy` object and get the reference to the original `sessionStorage`. Is there a better way to do this?

### Background

If it helps here are examples of only wrapping either `sessionStorage` or `Storage`, but not both:

#### Wrap `sessionStorage`

For the `apply` trap, I have to pass `getTarget` instead of `thisArg` because the latter is  `Proxy` object and if I pass it an `Illegal Invocation` error is thrown.

```js
    try {
        let ss = new Proxy(sessionStorage, {
            get: function (getTarget, p) {
                console.log("sessionStorage.get called")
                return new Proxy(Reflect.get(getTarget, p), {
                    apply(applyTarget, thisArg, argArray) {
                        console.log("sessionStorage.get.apply called");
                        Reflect.apply(applyTarget, getTarget, argArray);
                    }
                })
            },
        });
        ss.setItem("foo", "1");
        console.log(`Proxy.sessionStorage.getItem: ${ss.getItem("foo")}`);
        console.log(`Proxy.sessionStorage Worked`)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Proxy.sessionStorage Caught ${e.stack}`);
    }
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vay7urzg/)

Result:

```
sessionStorage.get called
sessionStorage.get.apply called
sessionStorage.get called
sessionStorage.get.apply called
sessionStorage.get called
sessionStorage.get.apply called
Proxy.sessionStorage.getItem: undefined
Proxy.sessionStorage Worked
```

#### Wrap `Storage.prototype`

Here I have to first create a new object with a separate `prototype` because the `prototype` property descriptor for `Storage` has `configurable` set to `false`. Once I've done that I essentially have to do the same thing as the previous case by passing the "unwrapped" `getTarget` instead of the `Proxy` instance pointed to by `thisArg`.

```js
    try {
        console.log("\n\n");
        SP = new Proxy(Object.create(Storage.prototype), {
            get: function (getTarget, p) {
                console.log("Storage.get proxy called")
                return new Proxy(Reflect.get(getTarget, p), {
                    apply(applyTarget, thisArg, argArray) {
                        console.log("Storage.get.apply called");
                        try {
                            return Reflect.apply(applyTarget, thisArg, argArray);
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.log("apply failed when passing thisArg");
                            return Reflect.apply(applyTarget, getTarget, argArray);
                        }
                    }
                })
            },
        });
        SPW = {};
        Object.defineProperty(SPW, 'prototype', {
            value: SP,
            configurable: false,
        });
        si = SPW.prototype.setItem;
        gi = SPW.prototype.getItem;
        si.call(sessionStorage, "foo", "2");
        console.log(`Storage.prototype.getItem: ${gi.call(sessionStorage, "foo")}`);
        console.log(`Storage.prototype Worked`)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Storage.prototype Caught ${e.stack}`);
    }
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yuv5rsge/)

Result:

```
Storage.get proxy called
Storage.get proxy called
Storage.get.apply called
Storage.get.apply called
Storage.prototype.getItem: 2
Storage.prototype Worked
```

Comment: What exactly are the calls and/or assignments you are trying to intercept? Probably you shouldn't be using `Proxy` at all, it just makes everything more complicated.

Comment: I’m trying to intercept calls made by browser fingerprinting scripts. My intention is to log them and analyze the data they are collecting. Other scripts I’ve looked at fail to completely log all the data being collected, this is an example of how the fingerprinting circumvents attempts to intercept operations: by using a prototype of an object which is not configurable.

Comment: Could you add the concrete calls made by some example browser fingerprinting script, please? Does it only call `localStorage.getItem()` and `localStorage.setItem()`, or does it access the `localStorage` in any other way?

Comment: @Bergi the specific example that sent me searching in this case uses the prototype method I demonstrated at the start of my question. Part of the reason though for my approach is because the scripts are usually obfuscated so I’m trying to observe their calls through interception instead of reverse engineering. So instead of solving for a single website at a single point in time I’m trying to develop a broad solution that can observe arbitrary scripts along with changes in which data is collected and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this far too complicated. There's no reason to involve a proxy here, just monkey-patch the two methods:

```
const proto = Storage.prototype;
const originalSet = proto.setItem;
const originalGet = proto.getItem;
Object.assign(proto, {
    setItem(key, value) {
        console.log(`Setting ${JSON.stringify(key)} to ${JSON.stringify(value)} on a ${this.constructor.name}`);
        return originalSet.call(this, key, value);
    },
    getItem(key) {
        console.log(`Getting ${JSON.stringify(key)} from a ${this.constructor.name}`);
        return originalGet.call(this, key);
    },
});
```

Comment: I'll accept this as my answer as it does answer the question "is there a simpler way". However, I'm trying to wrap a large number of objects in the browser and I don't know all the methods or properties which are being used up front without reverse engineering obfuscated scripts for each website. It isn't practical for me to repeat this option for all the methods I may need, so I'm going to stick with my original method.

Comment: @MarkJMiller You can actually enumerate all the global native objects and their prototypes and methods. As for proxying builtin methods (be they native to js or provided by the host), we [already discussed this in your last qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778159/javascript-why-doesnt-proxy-intercept-methods/68779009#comment121551689_68779009) - it's still the same problem.

Comment: Added a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgzc9qev/) for this answer.

Comment: This answer doesn't cover the use case in full, as you can also access keys directly, `sessionStorage.setItem('test', '1'); sessionStorage['test'] // "1"`.