# Javascript Leap year date validation

Tags: javascript

I tried searching for the solution in existing stackoverflow answers but I was not finding a suitable answer...

I have 3fields..

- Year `select`
- Month `select`
- Date `select`

If you select the leap year means, February month date will change to 29 days.. But that still shows the 28 days.. Don't know what problem in my code.

```js
var numDays = {
        '1': 31, '2': 28, '3': 31, '4': 30, '5': 31, '6': 30,
        '7': 31, '8': 31, '9': 30, '10': 31, '11': 30, '12': 31
    };

    function setDays(oMonthSel, oDaysSel, oYearSel)
    {
        var nDays, oDaysSelLgth, opt, i = 1;
        nDays = numDays[oMonthSel[oMonthSel.selectedIndex].value];
        if (nDays == 28 && oYearSel[oYearSel.selectedIndex].value % 4 == 0)
            ++nDays;
        oDaysSelLgth = oDaysSel.length;
        if (nDays != oDaysSelLgth)
        {
            if (nDays < oDaysSelLgth)
                oDaysSel.length = nDays;
            else
                for (i; i < nDays - oDaysSelLgth + 1; i++)
                {
                    opt = new Option(oDaysSelLgth + i, oDaysSelLgth + i);
                    oDaysSel.options[oDaysSel.length] = opt;
                }
        }
        var oForm = oMonthSel.form;
        var month = oMonthSel.options[oMonthSel.selectedIndex].value;
        var day = oDaysSel.options[oDaysSel.selectedIndex].value;
        var year = oYearSel.options[oYearSel.selectedIndex].value;
        oForm.dob.value = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    }
    var min = new Date().getFullYear(),
            max = min - 13,
            select = document.getElementById('year');
    for (var i = (min - 100); i <= max; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        select.appendChild(opt);
    }
    date = document.getElementById('day');
    for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        date.appendChild(opt);
    }
    jQuery('.month_sel,.day_sel,.year_sel').selectpicker({
        size: 8
    });
```

```html
<select class="year_sel common_sel" name="year" id="year" onchange="setDays(month, day, this)">
<option value="">Year</option>
</select>
<select name="month" id="month" onchange="setDays(this, day,year)" class="month_sel common_sel">
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select class="day_sel common_sel" name="day" id="day" onchange="setDays(month, this, year)">
<option value="">Day</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="dob" value="" />
```

Comment: Please provide a more complete example...

Comment: FWIW leap years are more complex than just `% 4` - if it's divisable by 100 then it _isn't_ a leap year, unless it's divisible by 400, in which case it _is_. 2000 was a fun time for many reasons, not just the infamous "Y2K bug" :)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25588568/3783478

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript to find leap year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175521/javascript-to-find-leap-year)

Comment: I note that everyone is concentrating on the leap year issue (which indeed is a problem), but at the end of the day your code should work - just for more years than it should.  I think you need to post more context, like the contents of the year dropdown for instance.  Do the values _actually_ properly correspond to the years etc?  You need to create a [mcve] really.

Comment: I will post the following codes..

Comment: `var min = new Date().getFullYear(),
            max = min - 13,
            select = document.getElementById('year');
    for (var i = (min - 100); i <= max; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        select.appendChild(opt);
    }`       **this part is for year**

Comment: **and last part**  `date = document.getElementById('day');
    for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        date.appendChild(opt);
    }`

Comment: Please [edit] all the relevant details into your question.

Comment: Have you figured this out? You should pick an answer or let us know what's unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

This bit is wrong:

```
if (nDays == 28 && oYearSel[oYearSel.selectedIndex].value % 4 == 0)
    ++nDays;
```

It's [more complex than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm). The rule is: If the year is evenly divisible by 4 *and* either it is **not** evenly divisible by 100 or it *is* evenly divisible by 400, it's a leap year.

So

```
if (nDays == 28) {
    var year = oYearSel[oYearSel.selectedIndex].value;
    if (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)) {
        nDays = 29;
    }
}
```

For instance, 2000 was a leap year; that was unusual, 75% of the time centuries aren't (1900 was not, nor will 2100 be).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use JavaScript's built-in Date object. Just set it to 29th February for the given year. Then check if it was actually set to February (leap-year), or if it rolled on to March (not a leap-year).

```
var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
new Date(year + "-02-29").getMonth() === 1;
```

Comment: You can do the constructor in any way you like; the main thing is to let Date figure out the leap year for you ^^

Comment: I would not use the string format for the constructor though since date string parsing isn't guaranteed to be consistent http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html. You should use new Date(year, 1, 29).getMonth();

Answer (score 2):

You can use date object and compute final date of a month and process accordingly:

#### Sample

```js
function getDaysInMonth(year, month){
  return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
}

console.log(getDaysInMonth(2016,1));
console.log(getDaysInMonth(2010,1));
console.log(getDaysInMonth(2000,1));
console.log(getDaysInMonth(2100,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add a new method to the Date object:

```
    Date.prototype.isLeapYear = function() {
      if (0 == this.getFullYear() % 400) return true;
      if (0 == this.getFullYear() % 100) return false;
      return (0 == this.getFullYear() % 4) ? true : false;
    }
```

I've used this for years, it works!

Add the script some place in your code, then call it from the date you want to check:

```
    var dtTest = new Date();
    alert(dtTest + " Is leapyear = " + dtTest.isLeapYear());
```

or construct a date to test:

```
    var dtTest = new Date(2016,8,9);
    alert(dtTest + " Is leapyear = " + dtTest.isLeapYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the year, month and day inputs to a JavaScript date and check the converted date matches your input:

```js
const isValidDate = (year, month, day) => {
  const testDate = new Date(year, month, day);
  return
    testDate.getFullYear() === year &&
    testDate.getMonth() === month &&
    testDate.getDate() === day;
};
```

This assumes:

- year, month and day inputs are numbers and not strings
- month is zero indexed